# Swift: Looping through a Dictionary Array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, struct

I'm struggling to loop through an array of dictionary values returned from a web service call.

I've implemented the following code and I seem to be encountering a crash on running.

I'd also like to store the results into a custom Struct. Really having difficulty achieving this and the answers on here so far haven't worked. Would be grateful if someone is able to help.

```
    let nudgesURLString = "http://www.whatthefoot.co.uk/NUDGE/nudges.php"
    let nudgesURL = NSURL(string: nudgesURLString)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(nudgesURL!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else {

           let nudgesJSONResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

            let nudges: NSDictionary = nudgesJSONResult["nudges"] as NSDictionary

            if let list = nudgesJSONResult["nudges"] as? [[String:String]] {
                for nudgeDict in list {
                    let location = nudgeDict["location"]
                    println(location)
                }
            }

        }

    })

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? What does the JSON data look like? Perhaps it is a JSON *array* and not a *dictionary*?? In that case `as NSDictionary` would crash (and that problem comes up about every other day here on SO ...)

Comment: You assign `nudgesJSONResult["nudges"]` to a dictionary -- `nudges` and to an array of dictionaries `list` in your optional binding (if let ...).  This might be the beginning of some issues, but as Martin R pointed out, the question is unclear about what the problem is.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: JSON data can be found here: http://www.whatthefoot.co.uk/NUDGE/nudges.php. The JSON outputs fine in the xcode console when I println(nudgesJSONResult). Having difficulty then accessing the values nested within the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTICE**

This answer was written using Swift 1.2 and as such, there may be some slight stylistic and syntax changes required for the answer to work depending on your current Swift system.

**Answer -- Swift 1.2**

This line is crashing your code:

```
let nudges: NSDictionary = nudgesJSONResult["nudges"] as NSDictionary
```

You're forcing a cast that Swift can't handle.  You never make it to your for-loop.

Try changing your code to look more like this:

```
let nudgesURLString = "http://www.whatthefoot.co.uk/NUDGE/nudges.php"
let nudgesURL = NSURL(string: nudgesURLString)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(nudgesURL!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    } else {
        let nudgesJSONResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as [String : AnyObject]
        if let nudges = nudgesJSONResult["nudges"] as? [[String : String]] {
            for nudge in nudges {
                let location = nudge["location"]
                println("Got location: \(location)")
                println("Got full nudge: \(nudge)")
            }
        }
    }

})

task.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, been struggling with it for hours. Had previously only worked with JSON data in NSDictionary format

Comment: do you know the best way to store the data returned in a custom Struct?

Comment: You would just define your struct and assign the properties to the properties from each `nudge` object and add these to an array.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Struggling to set the Struct up so it stores the values in an array. At the moment I can only get location for example to store as single string, instead of an array with all of the location values

Comment: So, you just want an array of locations?  If so, you could do `let locations = (nudges as NSArray).valueForKey("location")` which will be an array of all the location strings.  Make sure to do this inside of the `if let nudges = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I created the following Struct which stored the data, and also lets me create dictionaries in the view controller for a particular index.

```
struct NudgesLibrary {

var location: NSArray?
var message: NSArray?
var priority: NSArray?
var date: NSArray?
var nudges: NSArray?

init(nudgesObject: AnyObject) {

    nudges = (nudgesObject["nudges"] as NSArray)

    if let nudges = nudgesObject["nudges"] as? NSArray {
        location =  (nudges.valueForKey("location") as NSArray)
        message = (nudges.valueForKey("message") as NSArray)
        priority = (nudges.valueForKey("priority") as NSArray)
        date = (nudges.valueForKey("date") as NSArray)

    }
  }
}
```